# line 121, in <module> gui = GUI(root) TypeError: GUI() takes no arguments

Tags: python

[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFMsh.png)

[test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCBwP.png)

[test3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3RtV.png)

line 121, in 
gui = GUI(root)TypeError: GUI() takes no arguments

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Your indentation is wrong in the `GUI` class. The methods all need to be indented.

Comment: Barmar so what do i do to fix

Comment: Indent the code properly. The first thing you should have learned about Python is that proper indentation is critical.

Comment: I don't understand how you could write that much code without knowing this basic aspect of the language. What did you do, copy it from somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

All your methods in the `GUI` class have to be indented so they're defined as methods of the class. Without this indentation, they're being defined as normal top-level functions, not methods. Since the class doesn't have an `__init__()` method that defines initialization parameters, you get an error when you call `GUI()` with an argument.

```
class GUI:
    client_socket = None
    last_received = None

    def __init(self, master):
        self.root = master
        self.chat_transcript_area = None
        self.name_widget = None
        self.enter_text_widget = None
        self.initialize_socket()
        self.initialize_gui()
        self.listen_for_incoming_messages_in_a_thread()
```

All the rest of the methods should be indented the same as the above `__init__()` method.